# Custom Counting Semaphore Class in java

Tags: java, customization, semaphore

I am trying to implement my own Custom Semaphore class. I have implemented the following code

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class CustomSemaphore {

    int permits;
    LinkedList<Thread> waitingQueue= new LinkedList<Thread>();

    public CustomSemaphore(int permits) {
        this.permits=permits;
    }

    public synchronized void P(Thread t) throws InterruptedException{
        permits--;
        if(permits<0){
            waitingQueue.add(t);
            t.wait()
        }
    }

    public synchronized void V(){
        permits=permits+1;

        if(permits>0){
            if(!waitingQueue.isEmpty()){
                Thread t=waitingQueue.removeFirst();
                t.notify();
            }

        }   
    }

    public synchronized int getPermits(){
        return permits;
    }

}
```

I can not use the original class in Java library as I need to add threads to the waiting queue according to a specific logic (unimplemented yet).

The problem with this is deadlocks happen and sometimes I encounter IllegalMonitorException.

Any points on what I am missing here?

Comment: If you are comfortable, move to java.util.concurrent package APIs like ExecutorService & Execturor

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1069/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor and http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/executorservice/java-executorservice-example-tutorial/  are two good ones

Comment: You're missing that `wait()` and `notify()` should be called *inside* synchronized block of object *they're invoked*: http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/01/08/how-to-work-with-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java/

Comment: so what should I use as lock object. I am sorry. I havent heard of what is objects monitor

Comment: The lock should happen on  object, which you are going to invoke wait and notify. "t" should be synchronized for wait and notify. Have a look at wait,nofity example : http://java67.blogspot.in/2012/12/producer-consumer-problem-with-wait-and-notify-example.html

Comment: @YogeshMittal this is not as simple as it seems. I believe it would be hard to build such semaphore using only `wait()` and `notify()`, these facilities are not designed for that. In original `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` you'll see thread parking and atomic variables.

Comment: The only problem is I want to allow only a particular thread to access the semaphore from the queue. i.e I want  my own waiting queue. Is there any way?